# Python - Sympy: how to compute lie derivative

Tags: python, sympy

Please consider the following script; how we can compute the  Lie Derivative of h with respect to f using python?

```
import sympy as sym

x, y, L, u , v = sym.symbols('x y L u v')
X = sym.Matrix([[x],[y], [L], [u], [v]])

# f(x,y,L,u,v) : R^5-->R^3
f = sym.Matrix([[ x + u], [ y + v ], [L]])

# h(x,y,L) : R^3-->R^1
h = sym.Matrix([[ sym.sqrt(L**2 + (y - x)**2) ]])

# L1hf : first-order lie derivative of h wrt f
L1hf = sym.diffgeom.LieDerivative(f,h) # ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use symbols defined in *sympy.diffgeom* when using operators from *diffgeom*.

Your setup could look like:

```
In [1]: from sympy.diffgeom import *

In [4]: M = Manifold("M", 5)

In [5]: P = Patch("P", M)

In [6]: coord = CoordSystem("coord", P, ["x", "y", "L", "u", "v"])

In [7]: x, y, L, u, v = coord.coord_functions()
```

Matrices are currently not supported, you have to express them as linear combination of base vector fields:

```
In [19]: e_x, e_y, e_L, e_u, e_v = coord.base_vectors()
```

Then define the vector wrt you derive as a sum of components and base vectors:

```
In [27]: expr = (x + u)*e_x + (y + v)*e_y + L*e_L

In [28]: LieDerivative(expr, sqrt(L**2 + (y - x)**2))
Out[28]: 
                                                        2        
    (-x + y)⋅(x + u)      (-x + y)⋅(y + v)             L         
- ─────────────────── + ─────────────────── + ───────────────────
     ________________      ________________      ________________
    ╱         2    2      ╱         2    2      ╱         2    2 
  ╲╱  (-x + y)  + L     ╲╱  (-x + y)  + L     ╲╱  (-x + y)  + L
```

To be more precise, you should define a new manifold of dimension 3, then a patch on it, then a coordinate system on the patch, in order to represent the *R^3* space on which you project. For simplicity, I used the projection on the same manifold to avoid defining a new one.

**NOTE:** you probably need the latest version of SymPy (version 1.0), earlier there was a bug which hindered simplification of *diffgeom* objects.

Comment: But what about 2nd order lie derivatives?  Is the following setup correct or is there a more efficeint way?  >>> `expr = (x + u)*e_x + (y + v)*e_y + L*e_L`
 >>> `L1fh = LieDerivative(expr, sqrt(L**2 + (y - x)**2))`

 >>> `expr2 =  L1fh.args[2]*e_x + L1fh.args[1]*e_y + L1fh.args[0]*e_L`
 >>> `L2fh = LieDerivative(expr2, sqrt(L**2 + (y - x)**2))`
 >>> `pprint(L2fh)`

Comment: If the result is correct, I suppose that's the way to go.